# Unable to open/download files in HDFS using Hadoop Web UI

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, webhdfs

I have configured a standalone single node Hadoop environment in an external RHEL server. I am trying to view the files in HDFS using Hadoop Web UI:
`http://<host ip>:50070/explorer.html#/user`. I am able to browse through the directories and even delete files in HDFS. But i am unable to download or Open(Preview) and view any files in HDFS using web UI. I can see all the files and open them from command line in the server.

I am getting an error as displayed in below screenshot when i am trying to open a file:

[image: ak_bng is the root user here]

Similar error is thrown while uploading files too. I am not using HUE due to some restrictions imposed on the server for the time period.

I am new to Hadoop. Can some one please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for failure of some operations via webui is permissions issue as the default user for it is drwho ex: Permission denied: user=dr.who, access=WRITE, inode="/":suyash:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x.

Workaround is to to use the console to do these operations if HUE is unavailable. Also could you try changing the browser/ clearing cache?